# How can I attach and delete a custom retention policy attached to content type in SharePoint programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have written custom retention policy and deployed it in the farm. Till now, I have been attaching the policy to a content type manually, but I need to add it now to several content types in several site collections. Is there any code? I have found some sources, but they did not give me a definitive answer. I have a custom formula, AND a custom action. How do I add both, and connect them together programmatically?